# Bold and italics math symbols

Tags: math-mode, bold, boldmath, boldsymbol

How can I make all the text in math mode as bold and italics? I need some code which will make all the math text bold and italics at once.

Comment: `bm` package `\bm{x}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I set all of the text to be like this all at once? Is there any preamble settings?

Comment: You also can use `{\boldmath $ some math formula $ ]`.

Comment: oh for all the math use `\boldmath` as Bernard just showed (no package needed)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may help you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\mathversion{bold}%this does the trick
\begin{document}

This is for test $a+b=c\alpha\beta\gamma$
\end{document}
```

Merry X-Mas